# Cyrillic output is different in 3 browsers

Tags: php, html, cyrillic

In the website of my company, i added search function. You wrote min and max cc of the glass you want, and it filters from database and shows you result.
The problem is, in English and Bulgarian(cyrillic), in the result page, characters are ruined.
It only happens at that page.

I am using index.php only. And in every page, only content is changing with php.
The website is sales.atmar.bg.

I saved all php files UTF-8 without BOM.

I am suspecting of not encoding/decoding may cause the problem but all other pages are made the same way.

---

20.03.2014

I've decided to change the question. 
I've searched glasses between 140cc and 170cc.

I am sharing screenshots with 3 browsers. In ie everything is perfect, in ff everything is ruined, in chrome only title is ruined.

Is there something to do about browser accordability?

1:

[image]

2:

[image]

3:

[image]

Comment: You've just shown some html scaffolding. you need to show what this `view_search_page()` function does, and how you're pulling your "search" text from a database(?). Plus, none of your html sets a character set, etc...

Comment: You saved as UTF8, do you also SERVE them as UTF8 and is the Cyrillic content UTF8?

Comment: Consider using switch() :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your html code move

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;" charset="UTF-8">
```

right after `<head>` because

> Always declare the encoding of your document using a meta element with a charset attribute, or using the http-equiv and content attributes (called a pragma directive). The declaration should fit completely within the first 1024 bytes at the start of the file, so it's best to put it immediately after the opening head tag.
>   [source](http://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations)

And the correct way to write meta is

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

Also you should send proper content-type header in index.php **before any output**:

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");
```

Actually both solutions work alone, but I am using them together.

Comment: Wrote new meta, the same happened. But when moved the meta before the title after head tag, it solved. Thank you.